# Extract base64 image from string and post it with form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to upload a image with my form in my `Laravel` project. I have a Image cropper that saves the image as `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/..`

the cropper sends a `JSON` string which contains a `base64` encoded string of the file, i need to parse the `JSON` string to an object and then extract the `base64` string and turn that into a file object.

I am using `Image Intervention` for the upload process

Controller function

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {

        // save post in db

        $post = new Post;

        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->user_id = auth()->id();



        if ($request->hasFile('featimage')) {
            $image = $request->file('featimage');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getCLientOriginalExtension();

            $image = trim($image);
            $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
            $image = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $image);
            $image = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $image);
            $image = str_replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '', $image);
            $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);

            $imagedata = base64_decode($image);
            //Set image whole path here 

            $location = public_path('images/uploads/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->save($location);
            $post->image = $filename;
        }

        $post->save();

        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);


        Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was saved successfully!');

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);

                    }
```

View

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('posts.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{{ csrf_field() }}

<fieldset class="form-group">
<label for="featimage">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control slim" data-ratio="4:3" name="featimage">

<label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Post Body</label>
<textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" rows="10" name="body"></textarea>
</fieldset>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit">Save</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" name="submit">Cancel</button>

</form>
```

I have read other posts like this and i'm clearly missing something but i just don't know what.

Comment: would you like to upload base64 image to your server ?

Comment: yes i would like to upload it to my public/images/uploads folder and save the filename in my db

Comment: Please can you provide a link to the cropper library you're using as well as the javascript you have to initialise it? Also, is `$request->hasFile('featimage')` **definitely** evaluating to `true`??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function.

```
    function uploadImage($base_64_string,$image_name)
{

    preg_match("/^data:image\/(.*);base64/i", $base_64_string, $match);
    $extension_array = explode('/', (explode(';', $base_64_string))[0]);
    $extension = end($extension_array);

    $img = $base_64_string;
    if ($extension == 'png' || $extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg'){
        $img = str_replace('data:image/' . $extension . ';base64,', '', $img);}
    elseif ($extension == 'mp4' || $extension == 'mov'){
        $img = str_replace('data:video/' . $extension . ';base64,', '', $img);
    }
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

    $data = base64_decode($img);

    $fileNameI = $image_name.'_'.rand().time() . '.' . $extension;

//Uploading Image To S3 Bucket
    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3-image');
    $filePath = Config::get('common.Image_Folder') . $fileNameI;
    $s3->put($filePath, $data, 'public');

    return $fileNameI;
}
```

If you don't have Bucket the you can store image in your local directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will work for you.

```
$featimage = $request->featimage; // base64 encoded image string

if (!empty($featimage)) {
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $featimage);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $imagename = rand(1, 999) . time() . '.png';
    $RootPath = public_path("images/uploads/"); // path where you want to upload image
    if (!File::exists($categoryRootPath)) {
        File::makeDirectory($categoryRootPath, 0777, true, true);
    }

    file_put_contents($RootPath . $imagename, $image_base64);

    $post->image = $imagename;  
}
```

Comment: did you send your image as a base64 string to the controller?

Comment: When i crop my image it outputs a base64 string so i need to decode it and upload it to the server

Comment: ok if you assign your base64 string to "$featimage" variable on the above code it will definitely work I tested at my end.

Comment: Do i need to write javascript to achieve this? could you show me an example

Comment: no need to use javascript. just try to assign "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/.." string to  $featimage; and change your upload path. i clearly mention comment in code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in my program and I got a lot of error. If your trying to give input as base64 encoded string as `'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/..'` and convert it to image file then use the below code:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->title;
$post->body = $request->body;
$post->user_id = auth()->id();

if ($request->featimage) {
    $image = $request->featimage; // your base64 encoded
    $filename = time() . '.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];

    $image = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $image);
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
    $location = public_path('images/uploads/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image)->save($location);
    $post->image = $filename;
}

$post->save();
```

If you are trying to take normal image file and save it in a public folder as well convert it to base64 format then use the following code.

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->title;
$post->body = $request->body;
$post->user_id = auth()->id();

if ($request->hasFile('featimage')) {
    $image = $request->file('featimage'); 
    $extension = $image->getCLientOriginalExtension(); //gives extension of image
    $filename = time() . '.' . $extension; //gives filename

    $location = public_path('images/uploads/' . $filename); //sets path

    $image = Image::make($image)->save($location); //makes image and saves it to that location

    $base64 = 'data:image/' . $extension . ';base64,' . base64_encode($image); //changes image to base64 image

    $post->image = $filename;
}

$post->save();
```

I hope the following code provides you the solution. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hello this didnt work for me thank you for your help though

Comment: Have you installed image intervention package? Also make images/uploads folder. Then it will work beacuse it is working fine in my code. And I was too having this problem once i solved it using the same code.  Thank you for your response though.

Comment: Yes i have the image intervention package i can upload a image via a standard upload input with no issue.

Comment: Its not detecting the "featimage" name tag i think i may require some js to get this working

Comment: If you are using base64 then donot use  $request->hasFile('featimage') because base64 is not a file simply use $request->featimage